# After using onSelect on jQuery Datepicker, calendar will not show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm trying to use onSelect so that users don't have to press a button in order to submit the dates that they are looking for. After I add the onSelect part of the code the calendar will not show up.

This is my HTML

```
                <form action="index.php" id="calendarForm" method="POST">
                    <p>Date:
                        <input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
                    </p>
                    <button type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
<script>        
    $(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: function(date) {
            $("#submit").click();

    });
    $('#date').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
    });  
  </script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try $("#calendarForm").submit();

Comment: whenever your JS doesn't work ,then open browser console and see the error before asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the function :

```
<script>        
    $(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: function(date) {
            $("#submit").click();
        }
    });
    $('#date').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
    });  
  </script>
```

Comment: wow, that's so stupid of me, this was blowing my mind as to why it wasn't working, thanks

Comment: @Karma no problem :)!

Answer (score 0):

`$("#submit").click();` should be `$("#submit").trigger('click');`